# How to send e-mail to a group of email addresses of CRM 4.0?

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Have a CRM 4.0 database with about 20 thousand or so accounts. I want to send an email, with a template to a group of email addresses within CRM. I can send to ONE email address but I can't to a group of email addresses. I was also wanting to have the email addresses in BCC, sort of like a distribution list or a notification list, but only emailing to those people in that group.

Answer (score 1):

The CRM-way to do this is to send distinct email to each distinct recipient, not using BCC. To do this you should add recipients to some list (using the advanced find is good way to add lots of them quickly). Then you should start a campaign and create campaign activity of type email (or mail-merge email, depending on your specific requirements).

Comment: will try thx.Also have a group of email addresses on outlook and when i send email from my hotmail or gmail account,it dont delever to crm.I think i should define this email group to Crm. How can i do it ?

Comment: I think this should be another question. If I understand correctly, you want to send email from hotmail to outlook account and see the email in CRM. Way to make it work depends on your CRM email configuration. Do you use email router or outlook plugin? What are settings of router/plugin? I think you should ask another question and provide details I already mentioned and maybe some others

Comment: i use email router and could see any settings about email gruops.Glad for your reply thx,i have2 research